# Use haptics like Messages for other Apple Watch apps

Tags: notifications, apple-watch, haptic-feedback

When I receive iMessage or SMS notifications on my Watch, it gives a gentle haptic tap. Notifications from other messaging apps (forwarded from my iPhone of course), e.g. Discord and Signal, give a much more disruptive buzz. Is there a way for me as a user to have it use the gentler Messages notification for other apps as well? If not, is it something the iOS developers could implement, or is it only available to native Watch apps? (or is it another of the infamous private Apple APIs?)